# Sufficiency for proof that if $P \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, such that $P^2 = P$ then $V = \text{null}(P) \oplus \text{range}(P).$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof, direct-sum

I have seen numerous proofs of this result, and understand why they are true.  For instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522963/show-that-if-p-v-to-v-is-a-linear-map-such-that-p2-p-then-v-ker-p) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360951/suppose-p-in-mathscrlv-and-p2-p-prove-that-v-textnullp-oplu) use the same method - writing $v = Pv + (I - P)v$ and then continuing on in a straightforward manner.  However, I was curious as to why it might not be sufficient to prove the result in the following way:

Since $P^2 = P$, then we have $P(P - I) = 0$, implying that $P = 0$ or $P = I$.  Then if $P = 0$, $\text{null}(P) = V$ and $\text{range}(P) = \{0\}$, so $V = \text{null}(P) \oplus \text{range}(P).$  Else, if $P = I$, then $\text{range}(P) = V$ and $\text{null}(P) = \{0\}$, giving the same desired result.

What am I missing in the above logic - is there a linear map $P$ that satisfies the above relation but is not the zero function or the identity function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One can have all of $P^2=P$, $P\ne0$ and $P\ne I$.

Comment: @LordShark conrgatulations on the 100k!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where you go wrong:

> We have $P(P-I) = 0$, implying that $P = 0$ or $P = I$

It is true for real numbers (or numbers from your preferred field) that, for $a,b \in \Bbb R$, $ab = 0$ implies that $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.  The analogous statement for matrices, however, is **not** true.  That is, we can find two non-zero matrices $A,B$ such that $AB = 0$.

For a concrete example, consider the projection matrix
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
verify that $P^2 = P$.  However, you can see that we have neither $P = 0$ or $P = I$.  Consequently, $P$ and $(P-I)$ are non-zero matrices which have a product of $0$.

Comment: Ah thank you!  I have been studying Axler's Linear Algebra Book, and have not been thinking of $P$ as a matrix (even though any linear map can be thought of as one).  This example helps a lot!

Comment: The matrix is a convenient shorthand, but if you prefer we could frame things just as easily in terms of linear maps.  In terms of transformations, $P:\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ is the linear map
$$
P(x,y) = (x,0)
$$
and you can verify that neither $P$ nor $P - I$ is the zero map.  The key observation in this language is that, for transformations $S,T$, $S \circ T = 0$ is not enough to guarantee that $S = 0$ or $T = 0$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense - this example drives home the point.  Also thank you for introducing me to the alternative proof tag!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $P^2 = P$ but $P \neq 0,I$.

Answer (score 0):

In general an endomorphism $P$ of a vector space satisfying $P^2=P$ is a projection map (which is why it is called$~P$). There is a projection map associated to any decomposition $V=A\oplus B$ of the whole space as a direct sum of (complementary) subspaces $A,B$, called the projection onto $A$ parallel to $B$, and it sends $a+b\mapsto a$ whenever $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ (by the direct sum every vector can be uniquely written as such $a+b$, which shows that such a map is defined; it is easily seen to be linear). Also $A$ and $B$ are eigenspaces for eigenvalues $1$ respectively $B$ (so $P$ is diagonalisable), and therefore they are equal to the image respectively null space of $P$.

If $\dim(V)>1$ there are many such decompositions (infinitely many if the field is infinite), and the cases $P=0$ and $P=I$ correspond only to the trivial cases where $A$ respectively $B$ is $\{0\}$ and the other one is all of $V$, so $P^2=P$ is very far from implying that one is in one of these two cases.